# Customize view of document library

Tags: 2010, visual-studio, view

I want to order the view of the document library in the descending order it was created.

My code for doing such is:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string webApp = "http://bipc11:1234/sites/";
    string subSite = "bestpractices";
    string url = webApp+subSite;
    using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite(@"http://bipc11:1234/sites/bestpractices/"))
    {
        using (SPWeb web = siteCollection.RootWeb)
        {
            if (web != null)
            {
                SPListCollection docLibColl = web.GetListsOfType(SPBaseType.DocumentLibrary);
                foreach (SPList list in docLibColl)
                {
                    modifyView(list.Title,web);                             

                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Success");
        }

    }
 }
 static void modifyView(string title,SPWeb web)
 {
    SPList list = web.Lists[title];
    Console.WriteLine(list.Title);
    SPView view = list.DefaultView;
    view.Query = @"<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='FALSE'/></OrderBy>";
    view.Update();  
 }
```

I am getting the error at line `view.Query` that the object reference not set to an instance of an object.

What should I do?
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping through all Document Libraries in the Site collection. The above code returns one List name Wfpub for which default view is null, hence `view.Query` gives the exception. You should only retrieve that library which you want to change. Also do't dispose RootWeb, it is automatically disposed.

Comment: I want all library views to be updated.. @Nadeem Yousuf

Comment: Then put the code in modifyView method in try catch block, so that the code will not fail for lists like wfpub whose List.DefaultView is null.

Comment: One more help I need from you is that I am working on publishing site and I want to make these changes to purely document libraries only not style libraries or Master Page libraries. Is there any way to get the list of libraries that are purely document libraries?

Comment: There is no easy way of doing this. You can use a check if (list.BaseTemplate == SPListTemplateType.DocumentLibrary). It will limit libraries like List Template gallery, Master page Libraries. However, Style libraries etc will still appear. You may need some extra logic to limit them in the result.

Comment: Thanks for reply..
I will check it in "Switch" to bypass them.